# How to set selection item based on value JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, android-spinner

I have two JSON data which one is JSON for user, and the another one is for spinner :

this is the JSON for user

```
{
    "taxonomy":{
        "User":[
            {
                "ID":112,
                "name":"Tanaka",
                "city":12

            },
            {
                "ID":113,
                "name":"Sugimoto",
                "city":12
            }
        ]
    } 
}
```

and this is JSON for Spinner

```
{
    "taxonomy":{
        "City":[
            {
                "city_id":12,
                "name":"Jakarta"

            },
            {
                "city_id":13,
                "name":"Jakarta"
            }
        ]
    } 
}
```

I already parsing JSON into spinner

```
for (int i=0; i<data_city.length();i++){
    JSONObject listcity = data_city.getJSONObject(i);
    Spin_city modelcity = new Spin_kecamatandesa(
        listkec.getInt("city_id"),
        listkec.getString("name")
    );

    Str_array_kec.add(modelcity);
}

SpinnAdapter adapterspin = new SpinnAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Str_array_kec);
spn_edt_kec.setAdapter(adapterspin);
```

this my Adapter

```
public class SpinnAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Spin_city> {
    private ArrayList<Spin_city> myarrayList;

    public adapterDesa(@NonNull Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Spin_city> modelarrayList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, modelarrayList);
        this.myarrayList = modelarrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, parent);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Spin_city getItem(int position) {
        return myarrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int count = myarrayList.size();

        return count;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, parent);
    }

    private View getCustomView(int position, ViewGroup parent) {
        Spin_city model = getItem(position);

        View spinnerRow = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
        TextView label = spinnerRow.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        label.setText(String.format("%s", model != null ? model.getName_city(): ""));
        return spinnerRow;
    }
```

and my question is how to set selection item on spinner based on JSON user(like "city" equal "city_id" ), 
can anyone help this

Answer (score 0):

To check equality of both user and spinner JSON keys, you have to pass both ArrayList to your adapter so that you can check the equal values